# Rails model referring to new fake model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've got below model structure where I stored Books and SellingInfo (which represents presale and after sale costs):

```
class Books < ApplicationRecord
  STATUSES = %w[planned purchased].freeze

  has_many :selling_infos, dependent: :destroy
end

class SellingInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Because of ActiveAdmin requirements I want to have new relation to a model which will be the same as `selling_infos` table (the same columns, types etc.) but I'll use it only when `Book.status == 'purchased'`. In order not to overload the database I don't want to create new model, let's say `purchased_selling_info`, with the same data structure but create some kind of 'fake model' and use it as `purchased_selling_info`.

I was trying to add something like below to Book model:

```
# models/book.rb
  has_one :purchased_selling_info,
          -> { where(status: 'purchased') },
          class_name: 'SellingInfo',
          dependent: :destroy
```

But when I'm trying check if it works in rails console I'm getting an error:

```
2.7.2 :009 > Book.purchased_selling_info.size

NoMethodError (undefined method `purchased_selling_info' for #<Class:0x00007f9916f33200>)
```

Comment: `has_one :purchased_selling_info` creates an instance method named `purchased_selling_info`. That means instead of `Book.purchased_selling_info.size` you must call it on a specific instance like `Book.first.purchased_selling_info.size`

Comment: @spickermann lol you're right! anyway I'm getting an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column selling_infos.status does not exist)` - which refers to my where I guess. My assumption was that it would only apply to relationship where `Book.first.status == 'purchased'`. Should I do some joins to make it worked?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Does the `selling_infos` table contain a `status` column? If not, why don't you add it to it?

Comment: `status` column is in `books` table. I want it to work only for `books.where(status: 'purchased')` which means only purchased books should be able to create a new record called `purchased_selling_info`.

Comment: maybe you simply need a scope instead of an association?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use it in ActiveAdmin as `accepts_nested_attributes` with has_many relation so I cannot use scope because active admin doesn't recognize them as default.

Comment: @max I've 100% that these requirements will be the same. Which means if I create a new table `purchased_selling_info` I'll have two tables `selling_infos` and `purchased_selling_info` with the same db fields. All this will be done only to enable in ActiveAdmin adding new `purchased_selling_info` when `book status == purchased`. This does not seem to me to be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to storing records with different behaviors in one table is [Single Table Inheritance](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance-sti). By adding a `type` column you can have different assocations:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :selling_infos, dependent: :destroy
end

class PurchasedBook < Book 
  has_one :purchased_selling_info,
          class_name: 'SellingInfo',
          dependent: :destroy
end
```

When you load the records from the DB ActiveRecord reads the inheritance column (which is `type` by default) and will initialize that class.

If you don't want to use STI you can restrict the creation of `purchased_selling_info` either through [custom validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) or [association callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

```
class SellingInfo
  validates :validates_is_purchased, if: ->{ |si| si.purchased? }

  def validates_is_purchased
    errors.add(:book, 'wrong book type')
  end
end
```

What you're currently doing wont work since:

1. Adding a lambda to an assocation just applies a filter to the assocation. Associations are class level and you can't make them dependent on the attributes of an instance.
2. `Book.purchased_selling_info.size` gives a NoMethod error since you're calling an instance method on the class.

> In order not to overload the database I don't want to create new model, let's say purchased_selling_info, with the same data structure but create some kind of 'fake model' and use it as purchased_selling_info.

You should carefully weigh "overloading the database" against the added complexity and mainence cost of a hacky solution. Sounds like a case of premature optimization to me.

Comment: What I want to do is nothing more than create a new `selling_infos` record but with a different model name which I need to use it in ActiveAdmin and there's no other way to do it?

Comment: Don't you think that actually getting your models right is kind of more important then "I just want to do X as easily as possible"?

Comment: Sure it is, but well... unfortunately my techlead has a different opinion.